# Why would trying to parse downloaded .csv with SwiftCSV not be able to locate file?

Tags: ios, swift, csv, realm

So I'm writing a Swift app, using Alamofire, SwiftCSV and Realm [attempting to use Realm] and I've successfully downloaded the .csv from my server, but when I attempt to parse the .csv to even see just the headers, it's throwing the catch statement of my do {} catch {}

My ultimate goal is to get Alamofire to download the .csv > SwiftCSV to parse it into readable Objects [~200 of them] > then populate a Realm DB

you can also see the catch{} is being thrown before the .response() is outputting... can anyone explain this to me? is it on a different thread or what?

The crazy thing is the file still exists even when the app starts, so I'm wondering why it doesn't see it at all.

Am I just not understanding the CSV library methods??

**ViewController:**

```
var localPath: NSURL?
Alamofire.download(.GET, "http://wristaroo.com/schedule/wristaroo.csv", destination: { (temporaryURL, response) in
    let directoryURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    let pathComponent = response.suggestedFilename

    localPath = directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent!)

    return localPath!
}).response { (request, response, _, error) in
    print(response)
}

var filePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first! as String

filePath = (filePath as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("wristaroo.csv")

let filePathURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)
print("\noutside filePath: \(filePath)")

do {
    let csv = try CSV(url: filePathURL)
    print("test")

    csv.enumerateAsArray({ (array) in
        print(array.first)
    })
} catch {
    print("error outside")
}

var filePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first! as String

filePath = (filePath as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("wristaroo.csv")

let filePathURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)
print("\noutside filePath: \(filePath)")

do {
    let csv = try CSV(url: filePathURL)
    print("test")

    csv.enumerateAsArray({ (array) in
        print(array.first)
    })
} catch {
    print("error outside")
}
```

**Console Output:**

```
outside filePath: /Users/michaeldvinci/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/522F6430-CB63-4607-89B8-6B3B4D9A3100/data/Containers/Data/Application/4DAA3C89-FF7E-4A0F-B251-4ED1AAF34C25/Documents/wristaroo.csv
error outside
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fe648f1eae0> { URL: http://wristaroo.com/schedule/wristaroo.csv } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Accept-Ranges" = "bytes, bytes";
    Age = 0;
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 6909;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain";
    Date = "Wed, 27 Apr 2016 01:40:11 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=30";
    Server = "Apache/2";
} })
```

Comment: Catch the exact error and see what is the 'try CSV(..'  throwing?

Answer (score 1):

`Alamofire.download()` method download the file asynchronously. So the method returns immediately before downloading the file completed. So you try to read the file before the file will be downloaded.

To fix the behavior that you expected is move parsing CSV logic to callback closure of `download()` method.

Like the following:

```
Alamofire.download(.GET, "http://wristaroo.com/schedule/wristaroo.csv") { (temporaryURL, response) in
    do {
        let csv = try CSV(url: temporaryURL, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
        print("test")

        csv.enumerateAsArray { (array) in
            print(array.first)
        }
    } catch {
        print("error outside")
    }

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let directoryURL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    let pathComponent = response.suggestedFilename

    return directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent!)
}
```

Also, a character encoding of the file is ASCII, so you should specify encoding when reading the file.